# in_array returning single row in foreach

Tags: php

To get list of users based on location I am using foreach and in_array inside foreach. But it is returning only one row, there are many rows in the DB. Is this correct or not?

```
$users_list = [];
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
  $user_selected_locations_list = array("hyderabad", "mumbai");      
  if(in_array($value['user_location'], $user_selected_locations_list)){
    array_push($users_list, $value);            
  }      
}
echo json_encode($users_list);
```

There are hundreds of users staying in hyderabad, but I am getting only one user in $users_list array

```
$users = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 245
            [user_name] => Jessica Alba
            [user_gender] => Female
            [user_location] => hyderabad           

        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 246
            [user_name] => Kristen
            [user_gender] => Female
            [user_location] => hyderabad           

        )
```

Comment: [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) returns a Boolean. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: without seeing the DB data, and the contents of $user_selected_locations which you're trying to match against, or the rules you're trying to apply, there's no way to know if there is a logical error in your code, or simply the data does not match.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I want users_list where user location is in $user_selected_locations_list array. I am getting only one user, there are many users who staying in the loation

Comment: @ADyson I have modified the question. Can you please review it once?

Comment: A _description_ of your data is not your data. Please show some actual sample data from the DB, and actual sample of the $user_selected_location_list variable. Also we don't even know if your query returns all the necessary rows into $users - have you verified that?

Comment: @ADyson Added users data in the question

Comment: Your code as shown and with the content shown above works perfectly - both rows from $users are matched and returned in the JSON. See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5351122ec4c8bf2a252e4e287a7e9c34b2e0e679 . So either that is not your real code, or some of your sample data is incorrect, or is inadequate to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: The issue is before that code: foreach ($users. Where you SELECT and get $users